# How to find the difference between two time intervals

Tags: c#, asp.net-web-api

For example, how do I find the time difference between (01/23/2015 10:10 am and 01/24/2015 06:00 am), or between (01/23/2015 10:10 pm and 01/24/2015 06:00 am), or between (01/24/2015 05:10 am and 01/24/2015 06:00 am).

The main purpose: I have a scheduled task method that runs exactly at 6:00 am and the scheduled task is written in global.aspx. I want to find the correct time difference between the time I start the application and 6:00 am. Based on that time difference, I can keep the thread on sleep until that time, and then run the method.

From the solutions provided if we subtract higher from  lower value(10-6) it give a positive result. but if lower is subtracted from higher value (6-10) it give me a negative result. which i can't use as a value to be provided in this particular case: System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(TimeSpan.FromHours(result)).

Please help me out in providing the logic to handle all the
 three scenarios mentioned and give a positive result value.

Comment: Do you have your time values already stored in a `DateTime` object? If not, can they be? Please be specific about what you're trying to do. See http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask

Comment: @Esoteric Noted. I interpreted the question differently. It is terribly confusing. And everyone who has answered so far seems to have interpreted it the same way.

Comment: @rikitikitik Agreed. Hopefully the edits have clarified it.

Comment: @EsotericScreenName: actually, your edits have completely changed the meaning, and do _not_ help "clarify" the question. You took your own incorrect interpretation of the question, and rewrote the question to match your own misunderstanding of it. Indeed, your edit is self-contradictory (you combined the first and second examples into one to match your misunderstanding, but the third example was left as-is), and also conflicts with the last paragraph where the OP elaborates.

Comment: @peter : The section paragraph editing is done properly.I am correcting the question please check it once again. thanks

Answer (score 0):

DateTime gives Compare method, which can be used.
DateTime.Compare(d1,d2) returns an integer. If return value is less than 0, then d1 < d2, d1=d2 if return value is 0 and d1>d2 if return value >0.

Comment: This does not seem like it would tell you the _difference_ between two time values. Only which one is larger than the other (if either is).

Comment: This question is about the difference between two timespans, not two datetimes.

Answer (score 0):

If you have `DateTime` and/or `Timespan` types, you should be able to use the subtraction operator.

- The difference of 2 `DateTime` Values is a `Timespan`:

  ```
  DateTime dt1 = GetSomeValue()    ;
  DateTime dt2 = GetAnotherValue() ;
  Timespan delta = dt1 - dt2 ;
  ```
- The difference of a `DateTime` and a `Timespan` is a `DateTime`:

  ```
  DateTime dt = GetSomeValue()    ;
  Timespan ts = GetAnotherValue() ;
  DateTime delta = dt - ts ;
  ```
- The difference of two `Timespan` Instances is a `Timespan`:

  ```
  Timespan ts1 = GetSomeValue()    ;
  Timespan ts2 = GetAnotherValue() ;
  Timespan delta = ts1 - ts2 ;
  ```

Any the combo is invalid.

Answer (score 0):

In general, one can subtract one `DateTime` value from another, which will return a `TimeSpan` value representing the difference between the two. But it is not clear from your question what the context is and whether you already have `DateTime` values in the first place.

If not, you can initialize your `DateTime` values in a variety of ways. For example, if you actually have strings like what you wrote in your question, you could do something like this:

```
string startTimeText = "01/23/2015 10:10 am", endTimeText = "01/24/2015 06:00 am";
DateTime startTime, endTime;

startTime = DateTime.Parse(startTimeText, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);
endTime = DateTime.Parse(endTimeText, null, DateTimeStyles.AssumeUniversal);

TimeSpan timeDifference = endTime - startTime;
```

A couple of notes:

- I passed `AssumeUniversal` to the `Parse()` method. You need to be very careful about doing these kinds of calculations. Preferably, all your times are in UTC already, or can be converted before you have to do the calculation. Otherwise, if the time zone is one that uses Daylight Saving Time (i.e. most of the time zones in the world), you can get errors when dealing with times that span the switch-over from or to DST.
- The `-` operator is overloaded for `DateTime`, allowing you to write the expression to calculate the difference in a more readable way. Similar operator overloads exist for other common date/time computations.

Comment: This question is about the difference between two timespans, not two datetimes.

Comment: The OP wrote "time intervals" but from his example data, which includes actual _dates_, he obviously means some specific moments in time, i.e. `DateTime`.

Comment: @peter Thanks for your understanding.Your solution is good but it wont work for all the three scenarios mentioned.Please once again check on my requirement and help me on this and let me know if you have  any queries

Comment: @SaiKrishna: I don't understand what you mean. The code I showed will give you a `TimeSpan`. All of the mechanisms in .NET for waiting some period of time accept a `TimeSpan` value as the interval to delay. If my example doesn't answer your question, you need to be much more specific than "it won't work for all the three scenarios mentioned". What about this doesn't work for them? Please put your explanation in the question itself.